# adding programs to path

Tags: shell, files

I have a load of tools that are kept in the /opt directory. The tools are organised like this: /opt/toolname/tool.sh. My question is, how can I add the tools in my /opt folder to my path, so i can run them from any directory in a terminal.

I have managed to do this with some tools by creating a symlinks in /usr/bin; but with over 200 tools it is a very tedious way of doing things. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, `$PATH` isn't recursive -- and IMO, shouldn't be, so you may be out of luck. Best advice I can add would be to write a tool that keeps your symlinks in order.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only correct way, is to make links in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` as you described. Because in those folders in `/opt/toolname` there are normally many other files, not just executables. I would be grubby. Anyway, adding `/opt/*/` to the `$PATH` variable would not work.

If you have a list of the full paths to those binaries, you could generate the links scriptually.

Comment: Just `/usr/local/bin`. `/usr/bin` is managed by package managers and it's not idea to put out-of-package links there.

Comment: Yes, politically correct it would only be /usr/local/bin ^^

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to do it:

1. Make a symlink in `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/local/bin`) directory `sudo cp -s /opt/toolname/tool.sh /usr/bin/[unique_Toolname]`
2. Add `/opt/toolname/tool.sh` to `$PATH` variable `export $PATH=$PATH:/opt/toolname/`
3. Combine the above but use `$HOME/.local/share/bin` instead system `/usr/bin`

Comment: Should it be export PATH=$PATH:/opt/toolname/ right? Without the "$" in the first PATH.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the folders to your path using the following command:

`export PATH=/path/to/folder:$PATH`

You should include this in a shell script that will be run *before* you open a terminal window (such as .bash_profile in your home folder).

However, since path isn't recursive, you'll need to add each individual tool folder.